# ignore template parameter in type matching

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming

This is my current program:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<class Feature, class... FeatureList>
struct has_feature {
    static constexpr bool value = (std::is_same_v<Feature, FeatureList> || ...);
};

template<class Feature, class... FeatureList>
inline constexpr bool has_feature_v = has_feature<Feature, FeatureList...>::value;

template<class Feature, class ...FeatureList>
static constexpr bool isConfiguredWith() {
    return has_feature_v<Feature, FeatureList...>;
}

struct CanWalk {
};

struct CanNotWalk {
};

template<class... FeatureList>
struct Robot {
    static auto configure() {
        return Robot<WalkFeature < FeatureList...>>
        ();
    }

private:
    template<typename ...Config>
    using WalkFeature =
    std::conditional_t<isConfiguredWith<CanWalk, Config...>(), CanWalk, CanNotWalk>;
};

int main() {
    Robot<CanWalk> robot_A = Robot<CanWalk>::configure();
    Robot<CanNotWalk> robot_B = Robot<>::configure();

    return 0;
}
```

Basically, `Robot` is a struct that can be configured with many other struct (they are used as token here), then `Robot<T...>::configure()` trim and organize the template parameters passed into to `Robot`. In the end we have:

```
    Robot<CanWalk> robot_A = Robot<CanWalk, CanWalk>::configure();
    Robot<CanNotWalk> robot_B = Robot<>::configure();
```

Although duplicated features `CanWalk` are passed into as template parameters, they are all deleted when constructing `Robot` via function `configure()`.

This is working well until I add a template parameter to feature `CanWalk`:

```
template <int Speed>
struct CanWalk {
};
```

Now everything breaks since `CanWalk` is no longer a legit type, it needs a template parameter.

For error `error: use of class template 'CanWalk' requires template arguments` occured from:

```
template<typename ...Config>
using WalkFeature =
std::conditional_t<isConfiguredWith<CanWalk>(), CanWalk, CanNotWalk>;
```

How do I fix it?

How can I define them as:

```
Robot<CanWalk<5>> robot_A = Robot<CanWalk<5>>::configure();
Robot<CanNotWalk> robot_B = Robot<>::configure();
```

?

live code: https://godbolt.org/z/4K9TxohWq

Comment: are you planning to add more parameters to the features? Only non-type parameters, or also type parameters?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Currently only 1, maybe more in the future. Would this make a big difference?

Comment: If both type and non-type parameters are mixed, it will make a big headache I guess.

Comment: what 김선달 said. If you are planning to mix type and non-type, it might be worth to consider to make them all type parameters and use `std::integral_constant` or similar for non-type

Comment: At some point, one way or another, the actual speed must come from somewhere: the program must mention, say, `CanWalk<42>`. Where and how will this happen in your design? If `CanWalk` is only ever used with the hypothetical `AnySpeed` parameter, then it's equivalent to not making it a template at all.

Comment: I suggest creating a constructor(maybe `constexpr`) for `CanWalk` that accepts `speed` instead of making `CanWalk` have `speed` as its template parameter. It this way, you have to change `configure` to accept instances instead of types.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I'm hoping to use a templated `int` to set the speed. If speed set, the robot is with a speed (`CanWalk<Speed>`), otherwise with the other token `CanNotWalk`.

Comment: @김선달 I did think about that, but then this constructor returns an instantiated class, not a type. I'm still hoping to configure it into type.

Comment: What should be the type of `Robot<CanWalk<1>, CanWalk<2>>::WalkFeature`?

Comment: Why is `WalkFeature` a template? It takes parameter pack `Config`, but doesn't use it in any way.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik 
Regarding `Robot<CanWalk<1>, CanWalk<2>>::WalkFeature`, let's ignore such compleax part for a second. `WalkFeature` is updated to use the template parameter.

Comment: [Something along these lines](https://godbolt.org/z/63Wzq5s4Y), perhaps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see three challenges here:

1. you need to extract a specific trait (`CanWalk`), regardless of its parameters, from a parameter pack
2. you need to ignore extra copies of the same trait
3. you need to set a default trait (`CanNotWalk`) if that trait is not present

I don't know a better way to do this than recursively:

```cpp
// definition
template<template<auto...> class FeatureType, class DefaultFeature, class... FeatureList>
struct find_feature;

// next trait matches, stop recursing and return it
template<template<auto...> class FeatureType, class DefaultFeature, auto... Param, class... RemainingFeatures>
struct find_feature<FeatureType, DefaultFeature, FeatureType<Param...>, RemainingFeatures...> {
    using type = FeatureType<Param...>;
};

// next trait does not match, skip by inheriting from rest of list
template<template<auto...> class FeatureType, class DefaultFeature, class FirstFeature, class... RemainingFeatures>
struct find_feature<FeatureType, DefaultFeature, FirstFeature, RemainingFeatures...> 
    : find_feature<FeatureType, DefaultFeature, RemainingFeatures...> { };

// no more traits, return default trait
template<template<auto...> class FeatureType, class DefaultFeature>
struct find_feature<FeatureType, DefaultFeature> {
    using type = DefaultFeature;
};

// alias
template<template<auto...> class FeatureType, class... FeatureList>
using find_feature_t = typename find_feature<FeatureType, FeatureList...>::type;
```

this should work for any feature that is a class template and any number of non-type parameters.

usage:

```cpp
template <int speed>
struct CanWalk {};
struct CanNotWalk {};

template<class... FeatureList>
struct Robot {
    static auto configure() {
        return Robot<WalkFeature < FeatureList...>>
        ();
    }

private:
    template<typename ...Config>
    using WalkFeature = find_feature_t<CanWalk, CanNotWalk, Config...>;
};

auto robot_A = Robot<CanWalk<42>, CanWalk<25>>::configure();
static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(robot_A), Robot<CanWalk<42>>>, "");

auto robot_B = Robot<>::configure();
static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(robot_B), Robot<CanNotWalk>>, "");
```

Answer (score 1):

Removing some genericity, you might do something like:

```
template <typename T> struct Tag { using type = T; };

template <std::size_t> struct CanWalk {};
struct CanNotWalk {};

template <std::size_t N> Tag<CanWalk<N>> has_walk(Tag<CanWalk<N>>); // No impl
template <typename T> Tag<CanNotWalk> has_walk(Tag<T>); // No impl

template<class... FeatureList>
struct Robot {
    static auto configure() {
        struct all_features : Tag<FeatureList>..., Tag<struct Empty> {};
        return Robot<typename decltype(has_walk(all_features{}))::type>{};
    }
};

int main() {
    [[maybe_unused]] Robot<CanWalk<42>> robot_A = Robot<CanWalk<42>>::configure();
    [[maybe_unused]] Robot<CanNotWalk> robot_B = Robot<>::configure();
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1258a5ae89c47b60)

That simple way doesn't handle duplicates, but can with some extra work (idea is to have `struct all_features : Tag<Ts, Is>...` with `std::index_sequence`)

Comment: How can I use `float` instead of `std::size_t` for template parameter for `CanWalk`?

Comment: @Rahn By using C++20 ([example](https://godbolt.org/z/dhq14f8Kh))

Comment: @TedLyngmo Damn, clang hasn't fully supported C++ 20. But thanks for the code.

Comment: [`std::ratio`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/ratio/ratio) might be an alternative for before C++20 (or Functor returning the given float).